# How can I render my 2.4GHz antenna directional?

Tags: antenna, bluetooth-low-energy, bidirectional

With barely no knowledge in this field, I would like to render [my antenna](http://www.tp-link.fr/products/details/?model=TL-ANT2409A) used with Bluetooth BLE devices more directional.

I tried to shield the antenna with different kind of metals with no luck.

Is there someone to point a way in order to render my antenna directional? Perhaps surounding with something?

Thanks

Comment: yeah, just cut a tin can open and unfold it, and make it like a 'radar dish' pointing in the direction you want. That would only increase receive strength, and only if the receiver can handle multi-path/signal reflections. *i think, dont sue me if i'm wrong*

Comment: You'd do better not to disasemble the can.  See the old writeups on pringles and 2.4GHz wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the wavelengthn is quite short (~10 cm) it's very important that the reflector (that can be a can, as proposed) is placed carefully, in a way that the reflected signal is as much as possible in phase with the directed. You achieve this by having the reflecting surfaces at a distance that is multiple to half a wavelength.

You can try to tune it by measuring the signal strength while varying the reflector position, but I wouldn't expect great improvements unless you use a specifically made antenna.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment. I bought this antenna because of its directional characteristic. But, after some tests, it is absolutely not the case... I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Well, don't expect a directional antenna to be laser-like. It's much more complicated, and you'll have lots of reflections from the surroundings.